# Can I take a laptop into Japan?

Tags: japan, import-taxes

I will be flying from Australia to Tokyo in a few weeks time and was wondering whether I am allowed to take my laptop there?

Comment: I don't have a reference so not giving an offical answer but it would be mind mindbogglingly bizarre if you could not take a laptop with you.

Comment: @KeithLoughnane I've visited Japan countless times with a laptop and never had an issue, even when inspected by Customs.

Comment: Unless you intend to sell it, you're fine. I did it every time I visited Japan without any problems.

Answer (score 5):

If your laptop is for personal or work use then, yes, you can bring it to Japan.

If you plan on selling the laptop, that would be a separate question.

Please note that you will likely need a plug adapter (not the same as a voltage converter) to charge your laptop in Japan. Japan delivers 100V electricity with a non-grounded U.S. style plug. More information [here](https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2225.html).

Your laptop's AC adapter will probably accept 100V electricity but you should read the label to confirm.